# Removing seasonality from data

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a dataset depicting weekly revenue over time for a computer company. The plot for the data looks like this:

[image]

I decomposed the data into its additive components using the `decompose` function in R and plotted the various components:

[image]

Next I tried removing the seasonal component using the following code:

```
> RevenueDec <- decompose(Revenue)
> RevenueSeasonallyAdjusted <- Revenue  - RevenueDec$seasonal
```

However, I still get a seasonal component when I decompose 'RevenueSeasonallyAdjusted':

[image]

The y-axis has very small values but the seasonality exists nonetheless.

Could you help me out here.

EDIT: In the next step I tried using the `auto.arima` function on my seasonally adjusted data to get a forecast and got a plot like this:

[image]

Is this the correct approach to use, or should I try something different?

Comment: Why do you `decompose` RevenueSeasonallyAdjusted again? You already removed the seasonal part, so you should have all you need. If you are asking why you are still getting the seaonal part, it because it is calculated by default in the `decompose` function. Type `decompose` in the console and you will see that it is always calculated either by `season <- x - trend` (for an addative decomposition) or `season <- x/trend` (for multiplicative decomposition)

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Thanks David. I thought the same but still had my doubts. I have added some things to my question. Could you please go over them. Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth did you take out the seasonal part if you want to forcast with an arima? The seasonality is very important part of building a correct forcast. I'm assuming you are using `auto.arima` from the `forecast` package. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68812/auto-arima-and-prediction) or [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14742/auto-arima-with-daily-data-how-to-capture-seasonality-periodicity) on how to add seaosonal part to an `auto.arima`

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I removed the seasonal component because the data is revenue against time. I don't think that seasonality plays an important part in this data and that there must be some other underlying factor.

Comment: Revenue have to be seasonal. At Least weekly. without doubt yearly. anyway, if you want some syntax help, I'd suggest that you will post your data + your code. Otherwise it is hard to help you

Comment: So do you suggest that I carry on with my original data (with seasonality). Is the ARIMA model correct or should I keep exploring other techniques.

Comment: `auto.arima` form the `forecast` package should be a good tool. But you have to provide maximum information, which means seasonal parts, explaining variables and etc.

Comment: You can also try decomposition by stl. You could also try stlf forecast function and choose arima as a forecasting method.

Comment: @DavidArenburg One might deseasonalize data for the same reasons governments do it in their statistics - e.g. to make comparisons across seasons possible. There are a variety of other reasons people look at seasonally-adjusted data.